# Where On The Political Spectrum Do The Old US Political Parties Fall

Tags: united-states, president, parties, history

I'm not a poly-sci major so I need some help to figure out a seemingly simple thing. I've been given a list of presidents and have to do some data visualizing with them. There is a list of parties, and I'd like to sort them by left or right parties so there can be some kind of continuity rather than simply list their party name. I've been Googling but haven't gotten any clear answers.

But I'm not certain if I should be using our current definition liberal(left)/convsertive(right) or just go by how they were viewed by their contemporaries. I'm thinking I should probably use how they were defined as their contemporaries. So for example, though I don't know if this true, even though we may say Federalists are like our current conservatives in the US, maybe if they were seen as liberal for their time I should just categorize them as "left". Or maybe progressive vs. not progressive?

- "None" (Washington)
- "Federalist"
- "Democratic-Republican"
- "Democratic"
- "Whig"
- "Republican"
- "War Union"
- "Harding"

Comment: I immediately thought of [this visualisation](https://xkcd.com/1127/) which attempts to do exactly that, and lists the statistical methodology used to do so.

Comment: None, by definition, doesn't fit in one place. None of the above is an option in a couple of other states as well.

Comment: Wasn't Harding a Republican?